# How to update a jQuery code or any other JavaScript code inside a template (rendered function etc.) when one of it's parent template is updated

Tags: jquery, templates, meteor

I am running into a very strange situation, but may be because of some silly hiki duki, let me first explain the scenario.
So there is a template A, which is a parent template to B i.e

```
<template name="A">
 {{> B}}
</template>
```

and this Template A is obtained from a route with some parameters etc. like this

```
FlowRouter.route('/A/:id/:name',{
action(params) {
    BlazeLayout.render('layout_home', {template_name: 'A'});
}});
// There is also a parent layout in which Template A is injected, send or whatever
```

Now there is the child Template to A know as B, which is like

```
<template name="B">
 <!--HTML, with jqueryUI's sortable and dragabble elements-->
</template>
```

and following is the JS code for this template

```
template.B.rendered = function() {
 // console.log("B is rendering");
 // Here are some code for JqueryUI's Draggable and Sortable code etc.
};
```

So when I refresh the page with http://localhost:3000/A/21/44, everything is fine, dynamic data is rendering, every thing good, and I also get the message "B is rendering" to the console, fantastic!!

**However, when I somehow change the route to http://localhost:3000/A/23/11 without refreshing or reloading the browser, the code inside the rendering function of child Template B never executes again.**

I tried updating the rendering code from the route, but it never works, may be because at this time, DOM of template B was not prepared, rendered, created ...

What to do?? How can I update my code for Template B when Template A is updated or changed

Answer (score 0):

This might be a 'nasty' solution, but it might get the job done. You could set a Session variable whenever Template A is rendered, which is called upon in Template B like such:

```
template.A.rendered = function() {
    Session.set('triggerB',Date.now());
}
```

Since any Session variable changes push helpers in which the Session variables are used to be refreshed, you could put some code in a helper, which sole purpose is to run some extra code:

```
Template.B.helpers({
    'myHelper': function(){
        var bTriggered = Session.get('triggerB');
        // run whatever code needs to be run when A is rendered
        return ''; // always return nothing, cause the helper isn't meant to return text
    }
});
```

Of course you still have to have to place your helper somewhere in your Template B.

```
<template name="B">
    {{myHelper}}
</template>
```